# Fatal Error With EDI Disassembler in BizTalk EDI Receive Pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm receiving the following error when I use the `EDIReceive` Pipeline in Microsoft BizTalk 2010:

```
There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: 

"Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.DefaultPipelines.EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
Source: "EDI disassembler" Receive Port: "Receive 837P 5010" URI: "C:\EDI\5010InBound\837P\*.*" 
Reason: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.MessageCore.TransactionSetErrorInfo..ctor(Int32, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.MessageCore.EdiProcessingUnitErrorList, System.String)'
```

I'm assuming I'm missing some sort of required component but in my research I haven't turned anything up.

Comment: The first thing to try is a Repair on the BizTalk installation, then reapply any CU's.

Comment: Installing BizTalk Server 2010 Cumulative Update 5 resolved the issue. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Johns-305 You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Add/Remove Programs, do a Repair on the BizTalk Server installation, then reapply any CU's.